# How to create a appropriate database model for the IM

Tags: core-data

recently we're developing the IM feature for our app. And we would save the chat record with core data. The strategy we make are:

1. every account has a separate sqlite file.
2. every chat has a separate table (dynamic created, refer to this article ), however, the table structure is the same. such as,

   - sender_id
   - msg_id
   - content
   - msg_send_time
     ...

If we put all the chat message in a table, and we fetch the records by "fromid and toid" to get a specific dialog records. However, if we have thousands of thousands message in this table, we doubt the fetch request would be very slow. so we create a specific table for each dialog.

So, is there any better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Creating "tables" for conversations dynamically is a very bad idea. This will create so much overhead that it will make your code completely inefficient.

Instead, use single entity (not table, mind you, Core Data is not a database) to capture the messages. Filter by user IDs.

This will perform without a glitch with 100.000s of messages, far more than should be stored or displayed on a mobile device.